# Oracle Apex SAVEPOINT

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, oracle-apex, savepoints

I've tried many different code lines for this but i can't figure out what the problem is. Every time i type "SAVEPOINT [savepoint-name];" in Oracle APEX i get an error "ORA-00911: invalid character" and i can't create the savepoint. Does anybody know an option that works?

Comment: Works for me on apex.oracle.com, in process editor: <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ysYRTat.png">

Comment: I'm working on iacademy3.oracle.com and it doesn't work there

Comment: Which Apex version does that site use? Could you, please, post a screenshot which shows everything you did (while trying to create a savepoint)?

Comment: Please share a screenshot that shows where you're using the code.